# RTF String value of a BMP file

Tags: vb6, rtf

Please do accept my appology if this question is a repeated one. I have tried to google but I could not get the answere aI am looking for.
How do I get to convert an imgage (BMP or JPEG) in to its equivalent RTF string value? I will then store this value in to database from where I can load this string to display the image. I am using a third party control (TX Text Control 10.1) to display the image.This Tx Text control is in use in one of my VB 6 applications.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The articale is slight dated, but here is the RTF specification section youshould start with:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140283(v=office.10).aspx#rtfspec_24

It will end up looking something like this (from the same article):

```
{\pict\wbitmap0\picw170\pich77\wbmbitspixel1\wbmplanes1\wbmwidthbytes22
\picwgoal505
\pichgoal221
\picscalex172
\picscaley172
49f2000000000273023d1101a030
3901000a000000000273023d98
0048000200000275
02040000200010275023e000000000
273023d000002b90002b90002
b90002b90002b9
0002b90002b90002b90002b90002b90002
b92222b90002b90002b90
002b90002b9
0002b90002b90002b90002b9000
```

Most of the values, such as image width and height, can be retrieved in VB6, but as the article mentions, you'll need to use a function like [GetDIBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the byte values for the color.  And if you are unfamilair with using Declare code in VB6, a quick google on it can find lots of examples like [this](http://www.ex-designz.net/apidetail.asp?api_id=433) , and [this](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_make_gray.html), and [this](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_graphics/gdi/article.php/c2381).

Comment: I got your point but I believe I am not getting the answere I am looking for. The article describes the header part, footer part and the data(image) part there. But how to get this header part/footer part and the hexadecimal value of the image? That I want to know.

Comment: Well Thankx all for your help. I just got what I wanted from richtextbox and its deftextRTF property. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to load a lot of images then I wouldn't recommend this approach, as the size of your database is going to baloon. You would be much better storing the image in a shared folder and then storing a link to the image's location in a text field within your database.

Comment: Well, @matt Donnan , I will be using just 3 static images. Moreover, This is an maintainance application, so cannot change the approach which has been followed for long enough :(

Comment: @Rajdeep Which database are you using, is it MS Access as your working with VB6?